# Understanding the BGP Peer point, BGP Peer and BGP peering session

Tags: bgp, networking

In my test case, there have 3 ASs. the connections is below:

[image: Und]

I want to use this case to understand the `BGP peer` , `BGP peering point` and `BGP peering session`.

in my understanding:

1. `BGP peer` means the two peering point and the link between them. is it true?
2. `BGP peering point` should be the interface, such as `Ge-0/0/0`, did I get it wrong?
3. is `BGP peering session` means the two BGP speakers' BGP process TCP session?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

These terms generally rely on context and aren't all industry standard, per se.

> BGP peer means the two peering point and the link between them. is it true?

No, a BGP peer is a BGP speaking router, usually in the context of an "Established" session/adjacency.  So in the case of R1 peering with R3, R1 and R3 are both BGP peers.

> BGP peering point should be the interface, such as Ge-0/0/0, did I get it wrong?

This is highly contextual.  You could say that R1 is a peering point for R2 and R3, i.e. "point (node) in the network".  I don't think most engineers consider the interface as the peering point.

> is BGP peering session means the two BGP speakers' BGP process TCP session?

It doesn't really refer to the TCP session specifically, it's more generic than that.  You could almost use "BGP adjacency" interchangeably with "BGP session".